# Untiy android plugin class not found exception

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm writing an android plugin for unity to be able to check if notifications are enabled for the game. I have one java class with a method for checking if notifications are enabled. When i build the plugin and then the .apk with unity everything works fine. But after installation, when calling the mehthod i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat;
```

### The Java class

```
package com.example.plugin;

import android.app.Activity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

public class NotificationPlugin {

    public static boolean areNotificationEnabled(Activity unityActivity) {
        return NotificationManagerCompat.from(unityActivity).areNotificationsEnabled();
    }
}
```

### buld.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

### gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Haven't found a solution anywhere else yet. Thank in advance. It's probably a super simple fix that i miss.

### Update

- Custom gradle.properties in unity set with `android.enableJetifier` and `android.useAndroidX` set to true
- Jetifier was enabled in unity
- Androidx.Core libary was added to the dependencies of the gradle.build file of the plugin

None of the above solved the issue

### Solution

As Hamid Yusifli suggested in his answer a custom gradle build template needs to be enabled (Project Settings>Player>Publishing Settings>Custom Main Gralde Template) and the dependencies for the libary need to be added (`implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.5.0'` in my case). This solved the issue.

Comment: You might need to add the [Core](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) library to your gradle file.

Comment: I added 
`implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'`
to the gradle depedencies, but that didn't help.

Comment: That is the Google Play Core library.... What I linked to is the CORE library. Unless you have some usage for Google Play, try to import the correct one.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake. I tried a lot of different libaries and commented the most useless one. Here are some liabries i tried, that didn't work: `androidx.core:core:1.3.2`, `androidx.core:core:1.5.0`.

Comment: Are you currently using a `.jar`. or `.aar`?

Comment: I’m using .aar for the plugin.

Comment: Try changing  `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` to `compileOnly fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`. I would also try cleaning and rebuilding, most likely not going to fix it but just for sanities sake.

Comment: Did you enable "Custom Main Gradle Template" to reference the gradle file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, seems like in your case unity ignores your library gradle dependencies,
there are many different reasons why this could happen. To force unity to include missing dependencies you must provide a custom [Gradle build template](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html) and add your dependencies in that file.

Comment: I followed the first steps of your answer when first implementing the plugin already, but adding a custom gradle build template with the required dependencies was the final step for solving this issue. Also much appreciation to @raybarrera who also suggested this in the comments above. For anyone who may have this problem in the future you could change your answer to make the custom gradle build file step more visibile. I will grant you the bounty as soon as i'm abled to. Thank you again for helping me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**proguard-user.txt**

The solution of Hamid Yusifli seems great.

*I had a bit of a different issue, and I want to share it in case it might help someone else.*

**proguard-user.txt**
So you might have this file on **Assets > Plugins > Android** in my case.
This file can affect the use of plugins. I work with custom plugin I build and I had to include it there (see Image)

[image]

Another issue I had, was that I had code, that creates this file, so it would update in the build process and remove my plugin line.
So I had to change that code as well.

I really hope you don't need it, but if you do - I hope my answer helps you and saves you some time.